Fedora Linux VM on Windows 10 HyperV host behind a network proxy cannot access internet
I'm setting up a Fedora VM using HyperV on a Windows 10 machine. I've got it installed, the VM boots up just fine but I am not able to connect to the internet from the VM via the host computer.
Here's the setup:
Host Machine:
Windows 10 enterprise 22H2
OS Build: 19045.5011
Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19060.1000.0
HyperV Manger: v10.0.19041.1
The host is on a company network behind a proxy.
VM Details:
Fedora Workstation
version 40 (workstation edition)
platform_id: platform:f40
When configuring the network adapter for the VM I followed this set of instructions (I know this is meant for using Hyper-V to set up a virtual Windows machine and not a Linux one but I figured if I followed the same principals it would work. Plus, it's the only thing I could really find that is close to my situation).
After following these instructions I have the Internal Virtual Switch created, the Fedora VM running in Hyper-V is set up with that switch, the host machine has a NetIPAddress on the new NAT network and I can ping the host from the VM and vice versa. However, I am not able to access the internet from the Fedora VM. Opening a browser (Firefox) in Fedora and trying to browse to the internet produces an error in the browser saying "We're having trouble finding that site".
I don't know if it's having trouble because the host computer is on a work network and as such is behind a proxy or if there's something I don't have correctly configured in the Fedora VM. From everything I've read about NAT networks with VMs like this, packets should be routed from the VM to the default gateway (in this case the IP Address I set up for my host machine on the NAT Network) and then the packets should go out from the host machine.
Here's the output of ipconfig /all on my host machine, the details of the new virtual switch in the red box.

And here's the output of ifconfig on the Fedora VM:

I'm new to Linux configuration and have exhausted all of my knowledge I can bring to the table in trying to troubleshoot this issue. If anyone would help me figure out what I need to do to be able to access the internet from this Fedora VM running in Hyper-V on my Windows 10 host machine I will greatly appreciate it.
EDIT: I just verified that from the Fedora VM on Hyper V I can ping the DNS server the host is configured to use, so because I can ping an external ip address that makes me think that the either dns isn't configured correctly on the Fedora VM or something is configured incorrectly with how the host should be routing packets back to the VM. I initially had the default gateway set up as the dns server which didn't work, so I tried setting the dns server to be the ip address of the dns server the host is pointing to. Neither of them worked. Also, the network icon in the upper right hand corner has a question mark in it.
